# How to remove specific word from php echo which is being executed using mysql query?

Tags: php

I am modifying a PHP website, due to some condition I have to use existing MySQL query to display heading names on its relevant pages. The code is,

```
<h4> <?php echo $querysb['services'];?></h4>
```

My problem is, I am in a situation where I do not want to display the last word stored in the variable services. For example, if the services= football match, cricket match, I want to display only football and cricket, not the word match. Can I do it from

```
<?php echo $querysb['services'];?></h4>
```

this particular line?
Thanx in advance :-)

Comment: the code is <h4> <?php echo $querysb['services'];?></h4> and I want to modify the same line to display the desire output.

Comment: is last word is same for all titles?

Comment: @MahipalPatel yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$heading = $querysb['services'];
$parts = explode(' ', $heading);
array_pop($parts);
$heading = implode(' ', $parts);
echo $heading;
```

Comment: <?= explode('  ', $querysb['services'])[0]  ?>

Comment: @JimTebstone he might have more than one word to display, what he suggested is he want to remove the last word. not to keep the first one.

Comment: @Pezhvak I am new to this field can you please give the solution referring to my example :-)

Comment: it worked, thanx Pezhvak.

Comment: @anshuaditya awesome, it would be great to accept this answer so others can solve their problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would do the job?

In your case:

```
str_replace(["services=", "match"], "", trim($querysb['services']));
```

Its a bit messy, but just to show as an example

Comment: I don't think it will work this case.

Comment: @anshuaditya Have you tried it out? I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

so just try to replace your fix text with string function

```
<?php
echo str_replace("match","","your title match");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to show the 1st word only

```
$string = strstr($string, " ", true);
```